# Rollback en laravel no funciona

Tags: laravel, transacciones

Estoy trabajando con laravel y dentro de mi controlador, requiero guardar en dos tablas a la vez. Mi problema surge cuando intento hacer un rollback, este no me esta funcionando, ya que en la primer tabla que ejecuto el guardado si me guarda la información, aún cuando realizo el rollback.

Agrego código:

```
    DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
        $tbl1 = new Tbl1();
                $tbl1->nombre = "Jose";
                $tbl1->edad = 35;
        $tbl1->save();  

        $tbl2 = new Tbl2();
                $tbl2->profesion = "Ingeniero";
                $tbl2->salario = 35;
        $tbl2->trabajador = $tbl1->id;
        $tbl2->save();  

        DB::commit();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
                throw new \Exception("Error en inserción", 1);
                DB::rollBack();
        }
```

Gracias.

Comment: O sea... ¿Durante esas transacciones, hay una excepción y entra en el `catch`?

Comment: Es correcto. Por qué ya también ya intente usar: "DB::transaction", pero me hace lo mismo que he descrito.

Comment: Según [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php) "Cuando una excepción es lanzada, el código siguiente a la declaración no será ejecutado ...". Así que te diría que pruebes poniendo el `DB::rollBack();` antes de `throw new \Exception(...` para confirmar

Comment: Ya invertí las líneas, pase el `DB::rollBack` primero, pero sigue comportandosé del mismo modo, aún cuando invoco el rollBack, se guardan los datos en la tabla.

Comment: ¿En qué línea se lanza la excepción que hace que tu código entre al `catch`?

Comment: En el segundo insert yo provoco la excepción, al poner el nombre de un campo inexistente en el modelo, esto para verificar que si existe algún error tenga una integridad en mis datos.